# Map ip address to localhost

Tags: localhost, ip-address

I have a website running on my mac on mamp at localhost:8888.  On another mac on my wifi I can view the website, using

```
http://192.168.X.X:8888
```

(where X's are my computer's ip address). Except, I can view the html, but not any of the images as it is looking for them at

```
http://192.168.X.X:8888/images
```

rather than

```
http://localhost:8888/images
```

Is there a way to write `http://localhost:8888` and actually be directed to `http://192.168.X.X:8888` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit `/etc/hosts` and change the line

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

to

```
192.168.X.X localhost
```

That said, this is a horrible idea and will likely break things, but it can be done.